# Make wrapping div clear all the way to the left?

Tags: html, css

Im making a responsive site with dynamic content. I have a row of divs that will wrap at smaller screen widths. As some of the divs have more content and are taller than others, when a div wraps it doenst always go all the way to the left of the screen.

[image]

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ljmkb

I need a solution that works for different screen widths and for when the content makes the divs different heights, in other works I cant just set clear left on the 4th div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `float:left` on your div elements to `display:inline-block;` in laymans terms this will place them on the same line if there is space, or start a new line and place the overflowed element at the start of it if not.

By then placing the elements in a `vertical-align:top` environment, they will maintain their top alignment.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/57vpy/5/)